# Total execution time of a program with conditional branches in a five-stage pipeline

Tags: conditional-statements, pipeline, execution-time

A CPU has a five-stage pipeline and runs at 1 GHz frequency. Instruction fetch
happens in the first stage of the pipeline. A conditional branch instruction
computes the target address and evaluates the condition in the third stage of the
pipeline. The processor stops fetching new instructions following a conditional
branch until the branch outcome is known. A program executes 10^9 instructions
out of which 20% are conditional branches. If each instruction takes one cycle to
complete on average, the total execution time of the program is:

(A) 1.0 second

(B) 1.2 seconds

(C) 1.4 seconds

(D) 1.6 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
Total_execution_time = (1+stall_cycle*stall_frequency)*exec_time_each_inst

exec_time_each_inst = 1s [i.e @1ghz need to execute 10^9 inst =>  1 inst = 1 sec]

stall_frequency = 20% = .20

stall_cycle = 2
```

[i.e in 3rd stage of pipeline we know branch result, so there will be 2 stall cycles]

therefore Total_execution_time = (1+2*.20)*1 = 1.4 seconds

I don't know how to explain it better but hope it helps a bit :)